# successive unnamed field of width zero in bit-field does not change size of struct

Tags: c, bit-fields

Here is a `struct`.

```
struct {
   unsigned int a : 8;
   unsigned int   : 0;
   unsigned int f : 1;
} A;
```

`sizeof` struct `A` here is 8 bytes. I understand that. But now if I put one more unnamed field of width zero right next as follows,

```
struct {
   unsigned int a : 8;
   unsigned int   : 0;
   unsigned int   : 0;
   unsigned int f : 1;
} A;
```

Now, `sizeof` struct `A` remains 8 bytes. When I see reference, it says that using an unnamed field width of 0 forces the next field to align with the next integer. So, the `sizeof` struct `A` should have been 12 bytes here. Or does putting two successive unnamed field width of 0 not have its effect as desired ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C17 6.7.2.1/12:

> As a special case, a bit-field structure member with a width of 0 indicates that no further bit-field is to be packed into the unit in which the previous bitfield,
> if any, was placed.

So `: 0` means "stop packing bits in the previous bit-field". It does not mean "start packing bits in a new bit-field".

In case of the first zero bit-field, it means that no further bits should be packed into the previous one where `a : 8` was stored. If you add another zero bit-field, then the compiler still regards `a : 8` as the previous one.

As a side note, the compiler is allowed to place padding bytes pretty much wherever it pleases between bit-field members, depending on its internal size for what the standard calls "addressable storage unit". So you can never assume that the size of this struct is *guaranteed* to be 8 on a 32 bit system.

Comment: Please also note that bit-fields are poorly specified by the standard and very much non-portable, so avoid them when you can.

Comment: so is the size of bit-field system/compiler  dependent ?

Comment: @user9026 **EVERYTHING** about bit-fields is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Andrew so that means that bit-fields should be only used if we already know which architecture we are working on. I also read some where online that bit-fields make program slow and should be used only when absolutely required.

Comment: @user9026 yes, if the compiler must create extra code to extract and shift some bits from a word, that takes more time. It might depend on the amount of memory you can save using bit fields compared to separate integer fields.

Answer (score 4):

> When I see reference, it says that using an unnamed field width of 0 forces the next field to align with the next integer.

When you refer to some document, whatever your “reference” is, you should give a bibliographic citation for the document and, if available, a URL, so that other people can examine the document.

In this case, your “reference” is wrong. Specifying zero for a bit-field width does not mean to advance to the “next” integer or the “next” storage unit. Per C 2018 6.7.2.1 12, it means “no further bit-field is to be packed into the [storage] unit in which the previous bit-field, if any, was placed.” Thus, one bit-field of width zero means not to pack any more fields into the current storage unit, and a second bit-field of width zero also means not to pack any more fields into the current storage unit. It does not mean to skip to another storage unit, so two fields of width zero will not skip more than one field.

Also, the storage units used to store bit-fields are not “integers” *per se*. C 2018 6.7.2.1 11 says “An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field…” So the C implementation uses its choice of grouping of bytes to hold bit-fields.